# The group of quasi unitary elements of a (simple) Banach algebra

Tags: oa.operator-algebras, kt.k-theory-and-homology, noncommutative-geometry, banach-algebras

For  a  Banach algebra $A$ with invertible group $G(A)$ we define the following group:

$$QG(A)=\{u\in G(A)\mid \;\text{the mapping}\; a\mapsto u^{-1} a u \;\text{is an isometry}\}$$

What is  an example of a  Banach algebra such that $QG(A)$ is not a deformation retract of the  invertible group $G(A)$?

The  Grahm Schmidt without unitization says that for the  matrix  algebra, the group $QG(A)$ is  a deformation retract of $G(A)$

**Remark:** This subgroup is preserved by passing from $A$ to $M_n(A)$. So is it an obvious question to track this subgroup in the road of K -theory?